# Java Game Sprite Stuck

Tags: java, 2d, cardlayout

I am having a problem with a stuck sprite as soon as I switch to another JPanel via CardLayout.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private viewA v1;
    private viewB v2;
    private viewC v3;
    private viewD v4;
    private Player player;
    private CardLayout c1;
    private JPanel contPanel;

    // ############## VIEW A BUTTONLISTENER
    public class ViewAButtonList implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            try{
            c1.show(contPanel, "1");

            } catch (Exception ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
    // ############## VIEW B BUTTON LISTENER
    public class ViewBButtonList implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            try{
            c1.show(contPanel, "2");

            } catch (Exception ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
    // ############## VIEWC BUTTON ACTIONEVENT
    public class ViewCButtonList implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            try{
            c1.show(contPanel, "3");

            } catch (Exception ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
    // ############## VIEW D BUTTON ACTION EVENT
    public class ViewDButtonList implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            try{
            c1.show(contPanel, "4");

            } catch (Exception ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }





    public Game() {
        player = new Player();
        // load player settings from server
        //  ..
        //    contPanel = new JPanel();
     //load views    v1 = new ViewA(Player); v2=new ViewB(Player); v3 = new ViewC(Player); v4 =new ViewD(Player);

     c1 = new CardLayout();

     contPanel.setLayout(c1);


     contPanel.add(v1,"1");

     contPanel.add(v2,"2");

     contPanel.add(v3"3");

     contPanel.add(v4,"4");

        c1.show(contPanel, "2");
        currPos =2;

        this.add(contPanel);

        setSize(652, 480);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("GAME");
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);//go to end of view B (x=0), change to View A, close view B


       // Create 4 of each button to place in each seperate view (to swtich back and forth)
      // ................


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 new Game();
             }
         });
    }

    @Override   public void run() {         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    } }
```

Now.. everything works from the standpoint of switching between screens.. but my Player sprite gets stuck on screen after switch, but on initial load I can move the sprite around with the arrow keys. I am not sure if passing the Player on the new ViewA(Player) might be the culprit.. but I have a feeling that it is.. can't figure out what I am doing wrong..

Here's theplayer:

> import java.awt.Image; import java.awt.Rectangle; import
>   java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
>
> public class Player {
>
> ```
> private String playersprite = "playersprite.png";
>
> private int dx;
> private int dy;
> private int x;
> private int y;
> private int width;
> private int height;
> private boolean isFired;
> private boolean visible;
> private Image image;
> private ArrayList missiles;
>
>
> public Player() {
>     ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(playersprite));
>     image = ii.getImage();
>     width = image.getWidth(null);
>     height = image.getHeight(null);
>     missiles = new ArrayList();
>     visible = true;
>     isFired=false;
>     //default spawn location
>     x = 600;
>     y = 400;
> }
>
>
> public void move() {
>
>     x += dx;
>     y += dy;
>
>
>   if(x<=0){x=0;}      if(x>=640-20){x=640-20;}        if(y<=0){y=0;}
>   if(y>=400){y=400;}
> }
>
> public int getX() {
>     return x;
> }
>
> public int getY() {
>     return y;
> }
>
> public void setX(int x){
>   this.x=x;
> }
> public void setY(int y){
>   this.y=y;
> }
>
> public Image getImage() {
>     return image;
> }
>
> public ArrayList getMissiles() {
>     return missiles;
> }
>
> public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
>     this.visible = visible;
> }
>
> public boolean isVisible() {
>     return visible;
> }
>
> public Rectangle getBounds() {
>     return new Rectangle(x, y, 32, 32);
> }
>
>
> public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
>
>   System.out.println("X: "+x+",Y: "+y);
>
>
>     int key = e.getKeyCode();
>
>     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
>       if(isFired==false){
>           isFired=true;
>         fire();
>       } else return;
>     }
>
>     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
>         dx = -2;
>     }
>
>     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
>         dx = 2;
>     }
>
>     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
>         dy = -2;
>     }
>
>     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
>         dy = 2;
>     }
> }
>
> public void fire() {
>
>   System.out.println("Player used weapon");
>   // missiles.add(new Missile(x, y));
> }
>
> public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
>     int key = e.getKeyCode();
>
>     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
>         dx = 0;
>     }
>
>     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
>         dx = 0;
>     }
>
>     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
>         dy = 0;
>     }
>
>     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
>         dy = 0;
>     }
>     if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
>         isFired=false;
>     }
> } }
> ```

Comment: Where's the `Player` component?  I assume you're using `KeyListener` to move the player?  This will cause you problems

Comment: Yea, I am using KeyListener for the PlayerComponent.. adding to the original question now

Answer (score 1):

`KeyListener` require that the component they are registered are focusable AND have focus, this means that when you click something like a `JButton` focus moves to the button and the component with a `KeyListener` no longer has keyboard focus and therefore will no longer receive key events.

Instead, it is recommended that you use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as this API has the capacity to overcome these limitations